# font size is not constant across viewports

Tags: html, css, font-size, viewport-units

[see it in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAbLu.jpg)

I set font size of h1 to 1.2rem (i.e 19 px) , so it must be 19px across all sizes .
when i resize or reduce the browser width the font stays the same 19px . but when i click on device toggle and view as a mobile then fonts reduces rapidly .
why is it happening ? why does it change in mobile view ?

code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .main h1 {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <h1>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
        laboriosam explicabo voluptates. Optio officiis suscipit deserunt vitae
        pariatur, laborum quae soluta quos hic, beatae quam, fugiat laboriosam
        nisi? Magnam, ut!
      </h1>
      <p>
        recusandae libero voluptatibus vero, pariatur repellendus inventore
        distinctio perspiciatis impedit enim iure. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia repellat maiores est amet minus
        laboriosam excepturi molestiae cumque
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can take a look at medium website , its font is same 15px when inspected with mobile view too . this is not the case with my demo . what is causing this behavior ?
[image]

Comment: But you are using `font-size: 1.2rem;`  as font-size and you are not using `12px` as you are saying . If you are making changes in the CSS file make sure to remove the internal style since it overrides your style in CSS file. If you have an external CSS file please post your code and we will try to help you out.

Comment: my bad let me update the post to 19px . more or less its the same thing , it doesnt look like 19px in mobile it shrinks way smaller and no external css . im trying everything in head <style>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why didn't I think of that before? your code is actually working without any problem I just confirmed it the `font-size` is the same at all screen sizes what's happening is simple.

you have different screen sizes which mean different pixels sizes at the screen.

So the `font-size` is `shrinking` and `expanding` according to the screen size. You may see it small but it is most definitely an `18px` at all screen sizes nothing is being changed.

You can use the developer tools to confirm it. Just select the element using the select tool and it will show the details. Such as `font-size` `color` `font-family` and so on

[image: result]

[image: result2]

[image: result3]

You can always test it on a physical device to check that and confirms it.

Also if the font-size is small use the `@media` query to make it bigger at smaller devices. But as goes to your question. You don't actually have any problem.

### Edit

as I said before buddy you don't have a problem check this gif out and you will understand.

[image: result4]

Comment: yeah , that seems true . different pixel sizes ! but i never came across this problem . they usually stay the same in the dev tools and when i resize the browser but how to counter the problem i demonstrated in the gif mentioned above ?

Comment: i updated the post for you with an example from medium.com have and look how the font size is same for different screens . 17px is 17px for all screens

Comment: Hey there buddy, as I mentioned I did inspect the font-size in the element `h1` and it was the same as it was in larger screens. what you need to do is to use select an element or by the shortcut for it. `ctrl + shift + c` and you can hover over an element and the details will show up. After testing it twice I assure you the font-size is the same.

What's changing the screen width and pixels also you can select the element and see it's CSS that's being applied you should find that `1.2rem` is being used no matter what the screen size is.

Comment: And I think what you need to do, is when you `toggle the device toolbar` is to zoom in to `100%` maybe that will make sense once you see it. Because as I said before you don't have any problem maybe what caused the confusion because you were zoomed out.

Comment: thanks for the reply ! its much clearer now .very well explained .

Answer (score 0):

You are setting font-size as 1.2rem. This means 1rem is always equal to the font-size defined in html. The font-size of the html (which is often 16px) may change accordingly to the browser. Try setting the html font-size to 16px. As the snippet.
[Click here for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    html{
        font-size:16px;
      } 
      .main h1 {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <h1>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
        laboriosam explicabo voluptates. Optio officiis suscipit deserunt vitae
        pariatur, laborum quae soluta quos hic, beatae quam, fugiat laboriosam
        nisi? Magnam, ut!
      </h1>
      <p>
        recusandae libero voluptatibus vero, pariatur repellendus inventore
        distinctio perspiciatis impedit enim iure. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia repellat maiores est amet minus
        laboriosam excepturi molestiae cumque
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html
```

Comment: Can you add an image  showing the styles?
[IMG](https://imgur.com/a/Egxagib).

Answer (score -2):

try font-size : 12px **!important**;

Comment: That will not solve the issue using important is not advised.